# Mechanical Part Drawings

Tags: freestyle

Need to make basic part drawings like the attached, is there an easy way to make dotted lines and different colors or should I do a crash course on some other software to do this?

[image]

Comment: Blender is not designed to be CAD software. You should use something like [FreeCAD](https://www.freecad.org/) if you're looking for suitable free software.